# Problems compiling c++ with console on linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-construction, g++

I'm trying to compile following simple program on a 64-bit machine:

```
 #include <cstdio>


int main() {

    float a,b,c;
    a = 10.5;
    b = 20.6;
    c = a + b;
    printf("%d  \n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with following console command:

```
g++ -m32 file.cpp
```

When I execute the a.out file like this:

./a.out -m32

The result I get is this:

-1610612736

What is going on? What am I doing wrong? I get bogus result when compiling without the -m32 flag. Gcc acts the same way.

Comment: %d is for printing signed integers, you need %f to print floats.

Comment: You should make a habit of always build with warnings enables, at least the `-Wall` flag. This will make `g++` warn about that format code being wrong. Warnings are things that technically are correct, but still not quite right, and will often tell you about undefined behaviors in your code (like this one).

Comment: Also, you don't pass the `-m32` flag to the program. That is just for the compiler (and probably not what you really want. Just ditch it).

Comment: I need the -m32 flag, as I'm programming for a 32-bit machine on a 64-bit machine. By the way, what's with all the downvoting? Seems a little harsh to downvote just because I've overseen something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format specifier is wrong. It should be

```
printf("%f  \n", c);
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your format string is wrong.

You could just use iostreams and be done with format strings for a long while:

```
std::cout << c << '\n';
```